# Am I being tracked or something?

Tags: phone, scam

A guy asked to borrow my phone to make a call. Instead of giving him my phone, I asked what the number was, put it on speaker and made the call. Someone answered but barely talked, she sounded maybe confused? I hung up and told the guy she didn’t answer never mind, and he then tried to tell me he knew me? I’m confused and want to make sure someone didn’t just track my phone or something.

Comment: Im too confused of what is claimed here. *"he then tried to tell me he knew me"* - whatever *"he knew me"* means in this context. But in general: a phone call is a bidirectional communication, which leaves traces and various parties have access to these traces. It has meta information like the phone number of the caller, which be used to determine the person behind the call provided one has access to such directory information.

Comment: That looks like the opening move of a scam, specifically what is known as the 'Franklin borrow trick' or the 'Franklin effect'. It did not succeed, you're clear. But this is not "INFORMATION security".